# NSScrollView in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview

I am trying to get an NSSrollView with an NSTextField in it to work, however the scrollbars do not seem to respond to anything that I am coding.

I am declaring the NSScrollView as an IBOutlet, add it as a property and then synthesizing it. However, it's to no avail.

The scrollbars do appear when I resize, however they serve no function at the moment.

I have tried to use the apple documentation, but again, no joy there.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Please, describe the task and the problem precisely. What are you trying to implement? If you need to scroll the text, there is a control called NSTextView which already has scrollbars (i.e. is by default wrapped with a NSScrollView) and some extra features over the NSTextField.

Comment: The reason that I tried to use an NSScrollView with an NSTextField was that I couldn't write text to an NSTextView, as the compiler kept giving me the warning that NSTextView might not respond to setStringValue.

For my purposes, any container which scrolls will do the trick..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As You was saying *"For my purposes, any container which scrolls will do the trick"* You can use `NSTextView` in an `NSScrollView`. And for setting text You need to use ***setString*** instead *setStringValue*.

Example how to set text in `NSTextView`:

**.h**

```
IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;
```

**.m**

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    NSString *string = @"my text";
    [textView setString:string];
}
```

Don't forget IBOutlet `NSTextView` not `NSScrollView`.

`NSTextView` is in `NSScrollView`:

[image]

Comment: To add on to Justin Boo's answer, the method setString: is declared in NSText, a superclass of NSTextView.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the setString method is indeed the correct one.

However, I am still having a problem as the scrollbars still do not work. Irrespective of how much text I add, the scrollbars still stay in the same position.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Problem solved! I though you meant I still had to embed an NSScrollvew with an NSTextView.

So much for thinking it was a complicated issue, I just put in an NSTextView and it worked. Thanks a lot!